# Flutter Determine if this route is the top most Route

Tags: flutter, routes

How in flutter can you determine if a route is the top most route even if it has been popped but is currently engaged in a transition.

`ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent` will work when a route is pushed. However, when a route is popped, `isCurrent` will defer to what will become the new current `Route` (the one being popped to once the transition is complete) before the transition is complete.

How would you determine the top most route.

*This situation has arisen from a situation where the top most route determines the transition being used by a Custom `PageRouteBuilder`. It is supposed to always defer to the transition of the top most route, not use the transition specified by the  `isCurrent` `Route` before the pop animation has completed.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about your question as you didn't provide any source code, anyway i have few suggestion that you can try:

1. `NavigatorObservers` in `MaterialApp`: If you're using MaterialApp you can provide NavigatorObserver objects to trigger events during the routing (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html)
2. `WillPopScope` and/or `Navigator.popUntil()` method: a mix of them along with a state manager could help you to achieve your goal
3. Override the Navigator class to read its `_history` variable (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b5c5bae42bbecb71abdecc1484b5b3986ffc3bd0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L1309) and use it for you checks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. NavigationObservers is a way to do this but it is somewhat overkill compared to a simple <bool>isLast  in the ModalRoute. WillPopScope disables user gestures and that is the intended behaviour written in the docs. One way to achieve this is to access ModalRoute.of(context).controller.isAnimating as this will always be the top most route. However, the entire concept I was hoping for will rebuild the Widget during the build. Delaying this with a postFrameCallback means that the change in state does not take place before the navigation animation has begun.

Comment: In essence... Sorry to have wasted your time.